# Find the coefficient $x^{14}$ in the $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\dots(1+x+\dots+x^{5})$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This is corresponding to finding no. of permutation of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ having exactly $14$ inversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the product you have written down is incorrect. It should be
$$
(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\cdots (1+x+\cdots +x^5),
$$
at least if you want to count the number of inversions.

The coefficients of this polynomial are symmetric (i.e. the coefficient of $x^n$ is the same as the coefficient of $x^{15-n}$). Therefore the coefficient of $x^{14}$ is the same as the coefficient of $x$, which is $5$.

There is an easy combinatorial explanation: we have to leave out one inversion, and there are 5 ways to pick the inversion you leave out: it is one of
$$
(12), (23), (34), (45), (56).
$$

Comment: @pre-kidney Could please explain the combinatorial proof ?I didn't get  get it.

Comment: The inversion number is the number of adjacent swaps needed to bubble sort a permutation into increasing order. There are at most 15 swaps necessary, corresponding to the permutation that is completely out of order: $654321$. (First we use 5 inversions to bring the 6 to the end, then 4 to fix the 5, and so on. In total: 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15 inversions.) If you want a permutation with 14 inversions, you have to leave out exactly one of these swapping operations. There are 5 ways to choose which swap to leave out!

Comment: @pre-kidney  I tried thinking how $f(x)$ turns out to be the generating function for number of inversions, but I could not. I did some googling and came across an explanation in https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/MARGOLIUS/inversions.pdf . However, I am still lost. Can you help me see how this formula makes intuitive sense? Thanks.

Comment: Successively build up a permutation as follows. Suppose at stage $n$ your permutation is $x_1\ x_2\ \cdots \ x_n$. At stage $n+1$, insert the number $n+1$ somewhere into the string: if you insert at the end, that is location 0, and if you insert at the start, it is location $n+1$. If you insert at location $i$, you have added $i$ new inversions into the permutation. Thinking about this yields the generating function immediately!